# ld: How this ld script works?

Tags: linux, ld

In his article about understanding the [Linux Kernel Initcall Mechanism](https://kernelnewbies.org/Documents/InitcallMechanism), Trevor created a userspace program that simulates the mechanism for calling the init_module() of linux drivers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*initcall_t)(void);
extern initcall_t __initcall_start, __initcall_end;

#define __initcall(fn) \
        static initcall_t __initcall_##fn __init_call = fn
#define __init_call     __attribute__ ((unused,__section__ ("function_ptrs")))
#define module_init(x)  __initcall(x);

#define __init __attribute__ ((__section__ ("code_segment")))

static int __init
my_init1 (void)
{
        printf ("my_init () #1\n");
        return 0;
}

static int __init
my_init2 (void)
{
        printf ("my_init () #2\n");
        return 0;
}

module_init (my_init1);
module_init (my_init2);

void
do_initcalls (void)
{
        initcall_t *call_p;

        call_p = &__initcall_start;
        do {
                fprintf (stderr, "call_p: %p\n", call_p);
                (*call_p)();
                ++call_p;
        } while (call_p < &__initcall_end);
}

int
main (void)
{
        fprintf (stderr, "in main()\n");
        do_initcalls ();
        return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the __initcall_start and __initcall_end are not defined so the linker will complain and will not produce an executable. The solution was to customize the default linker script(generated by ld --verbose) by adding the following lines before the text section:

```
__initcall_start = .;
function_ptrs : { *(function_ptrs) }
__initcall_end   = .;
code_segment    : { *(code_segment) }
```

Here is a snippet from the output of objdump -t :

```
0000000000000618 g function_ptrs        0000000000000000         __initcall_end<br>
0000000000000608 g .plt.got             0000000000000000         __initcall_start<br>
0000000000000608 l O function_ptrs      0000000000000008      __initcall_my_init1<br>
0000000000000610   O function_ptrs      0000000000000008      __initcall_my_init2<br>
0000000000000618 l F code_segment       0000000000000017          my_init1<br>
```

I understand the mechanism, I just don't see how the linker understood that __initcall_start should point to  function_ptrs section or how the __initcall_end will point to the code_segment section either.
The way I see it, __initcall_start is assigned the value of the current output location, then a section function_ptrs is defined, which will point to the function_ptrs section from the input files, but I cannot see the link between the __initcall_start and the funtction_ptrs section.

My question is: How the linker is able to understand that __initcall_start should point to the funtion_ptrs ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
__initcall_start = .;
function_ptrs : { *(function_ptrs) }
__initcall_end   = .;
code_segment    : { *(code_segment) }
```

This bit of linker script instructs the linker how to compose a
certain part of the output file. It means:-

- Emit a symbol `__initcall_start` addressing the location-counter (i.e. `.`)
- Then emit a section called `function_ptrs` composed of the concatenation of
  all the input sections called `function_ptrs` (i.e. the `function_ptrs`
  segments from all the input files).
- Then emit a symbol `__initcall_end` again addressing the location counter.
- Then emit a section called `code_segment` composed of the concatenation of
  all the input sections called `code_seqment`)

The `function_ptrs` section is the very first storage laid out at the location
addressed by `__initcall_start`. So `__initcall_start` *is* the address at which the linker
starts the `function_ptrs` segment. `__initcall_end` addresses the location
right after the `function_ptrs` segment. And by the same token, it is the the address at
which the linker starts the `code_segment` segment.

> The way I see it, __initcall_start is assigned the value of the current output location,...

You are thinking that:

```
    __initcall_start = .;
```

causes the linker to create a symbol that in some sense is a *pointer*
and assigns the current location as the value of that pointer. A bit like
this C code:

```
void * ptr = &ptr;
```

The same thinking is in evidence here (emphasis mine):

> I just don't see how the the linker understood that __initcall_start should
>   **point** to function_ptrs section or how the __initcall_end will **point** to the
>   code_segment section either.

The linker has no concept of a *pointer*. It deals in symbols that *symbolise addresses*.

In the linker manual, [Assignment: Defining Symbols](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_chapter/ld_3.html#SEC13)
you see:

> You may create global symbols, and assign values (addresses) to global symbols, using any of the C assignment operators:
>
> symbol = expression ;
>
> ...

This means simply that `symbol` is defined as a symbol *for the address* computed by `expression`.
Likewise:

```
__initcall_start = .;
```

means that `__initcall_start` is defined as a symbol *for the address* at the current
location counter. It implies no *type* whatever for that symbol - not even that
it is a *data* symbol or a *function* symbol. The *type* of a symbol `S` is a programming-
language concept that expresses how a program in that language may consume a byte-sequence whose
address is *symbolised by* `S`.

A C program has a free hand to declare any type it likes for
an external symbol `S` that it uses, as long as the linkage provides that symbol.
Whatever type that might be, the program will obtain *the address that is symbolized by*
`S` with the expression `&S`.

Your C program chooses to declare both `__initcall_start` and `__initcall_end`
as of type:

```
int (*initcall_t)(void);
```

which makes good sense in the context of what the program tells the linker to do. It
tells the linker to layout the `function_ptrs` section between the addresses
*symbolized by* `__initcall_start` and `__initcall_end`. This section comprises
an array of functions of type `int ()(void)`. So type `int (*initcall_t)(void)`
is exactly right for traversing that array, as in:

```
call_p = &__initcall_start;
do {
        fprintf (stderr, "call_p: %p\n", call_p);
        (*call_p)();
        ++call_p;
} while (call_p < &__initcall_end)
```

Comment: Reading your bullet list at the beginning, the way you formulated it helped me understand, I understood each piece separately but now I see how it works =) thank you very much @Mike Kinghan. while(1) thank you ;